# GitHub profile picture upload not working

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, github, google-chrome-devtools

This is the response I get when trying to upload a ~1MB picture as a profile picture on GitHub:

```
POST https://github.com/upload/policies/avatars 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

```
errors: [{resource: "Avatar", code: "custom", field: "size", message: "size is not included in the list"}]
    0: {resource: "Avatar", code: "custom", field: "size", message: "size is not included in the list"}
        code: "custom"
        field: "size"
        message: "size is not included in the list"
        resource: "Avatar"
```

I took this from the Console and the Chrome DevTools Network Tab as there is absolutely no feedback from the front-end whatsoever. What could be the issue here? I disabled all extensions and tried Firefox but the issue persisted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/articles/personalizing-your-profile#changing-your-profile-picture), their maximum file size for profile pictures is 1 MB which is why they recommend keeping it at around 500x500 pixels. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like their UI actually displays the error.

Comment: This worked for me. My profile picture was only 213kb but 640x640. It displayed fine on my profile page but wouldn't update on other pages like in issue and pr comments. Reducing the size to 320x320 and re-uploading solved the problem.